# Get data from table using jSoup

Tags: java, mysql, jsoup

I am looking to get data from the table on http://www.sportinglife.com/greyhounds/abc-guide using jSoup. I would like to put this data into some kind of table within my java program that I can then use in my code.

I'm not too sure how to do this. I have been playing around with jSoup and currently am able to get each cell from the table to print out using a while loop - but obviously can't use this always as the number of cells in the table will change.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.sportinglife.com/greyhounds/abc-guide").get();
    int n = 0;
    while (n < 100){
    Element tableHeader = doc.select("td").get(n);


    for( Element element : tableHeader.children() )
    {
        // Here you can do something with each element
        System.out.println(element.text());
    }
    n++;
    }
```

Any idea of how I could do this?

Comment: Why do u need column count when using `for( Element element : tableHeader.children())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just a few things you have to implement to achieve your goal. Take a look on this Groovy script - https://gist.github.com/wololock/568b9cc402ea661de546 Now lets explain what we have here

```
List<Element> rows = document.select('table[id=ABC Guide] > tbody > tr')
```

Here we're specifying that we are interested in every row `tr` that is immediate child of `tbody` which is immediate child of `table` with id `ABC Guide`. In return you receive a list of `Element` objects that describes those `tr` rows.

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>()
```

We will store our result in a simple hash map for further evaluation e.g. putting those scraped data into the database.

```
for (Element row : rows) {
    String dog = row.select('td:eq(0)').text()
    String race = row.select('td:eq(1)').text()

    data.put(dog, race)
}
```

Now we iterate over every `Element` and we select content as a text from the first cell: `String dog = row.select('td:eq(0)').text()` and we repeat this step to retrieve the content as a text from the second cell: `String race = row.select('td:eq(1)').text()`. Then we just simply put those data into the hash map. That's all.

I hope this example with provided description will help you with developing your application.

EDIT:

Java code sample - https://gist.github.com/wololock/8ccbc6bbec56ef57fc9e

Comment: Thanks for that, looks exactly what I need. One question though, how do I implement that into my Java Project? I'm not sure what "Groovy" is...

Comment: I added a Java code sample - https://gist.github.com/wololock/8ccbc6bbec56ef57fc9e This `assert !data.isEmpty()` is only an assertion that checks if there is some data the map - you should delete this line in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much Szymon... worked perfectly!! Have a great day :)

Comment: Awesome :) I'm glad I could help you. Great day to you too :)